# How to get rid of spaces in a grid css layout and place the elements together one after the other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how to place elements by using `display: grid` without explicitly saying how tall the elements are. This is useful for example if you just have some elements and you want to stack them one after the other following a given order but disregarding the height.

So, given a certain number of elements with same width but different height. How can you place them together in a given order with pure css in such a way that there's no space between them. This is an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 505px;
  border: solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "b1 b2" "b1 b3" "b1 b4" "b1 b6" "b5 b6"
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: b1;
}

.box2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: b2;
}

.box3 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: b3;
}

.box4 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: b4;
}

.box5 {
  height: 600px;
  grid-area: b5;
  background-color: purple;
}

.box6 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: b6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fake content while testing a layout, **unless your fixed height can match together** *(left col is box1+box5 = 1600px and col right is 1300px so a 300px gap(s)/difference)* : White space are here because of the heights arbitrary given to children.
Your grid woks fine and is fluid :

**Tips** : For testing, use `min-height` on children or  the container, else use [fake content](https://lipsum.com/) / [htmlIpsum](https://www.webfx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/).

Your code with a `min-height` on the parent only

```css
.container {
  min-height:80vh;/* demo purpose*/
  width: 505px;
  border: solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "b1 b2" "b1 b3" "b1 b4" "b1 b6" "b5 b6"
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box1 {

  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: b1;
}

.box2 {

  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: b2;
}

.box3 {

  background-color: green;
  grid-area: b3;
}

.box4 {

  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: b4;
}

.box5 {

  grid-area: b5;
  background-color: purple;
}

.box6 {

  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: b6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
</div>
```

min-height instead height to the children :

```css
.container {
  width: 505px;
  border: solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "b1 b2" "b1 b3" "b1 b4" "b1 b6" "b5 b6"
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: b1;
}

.box2 {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: b2;
}

.box3 {
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: b3;
}

.box4 {
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: b4;
}

.box5 {
  min-height: 600px;
  grid-area: b5;
  background-color: purple;
}

.box6 {
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: b6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the designated heights, you can wrap the column 2 `divs` into a `flex` wrapper:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
 <div class = "flex">
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then change your `grid` CSS a bit to accommodate:

```
.container {
  width: 505px;
  border: solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "b1 b3" "b5 b3";
}
```

Now the only boxes that need `grid-area` are the 2 on the left (`b1` and `b5`) and the `flex` wrapper (`b3` in my code):

```
.box {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: b1;
}

.box2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box3 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: b3;
}

.box4 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
  height: 600px;
  grid-area: b5;
  background-color: purple;
}

.box6 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-area: b3;
}
```

Check this demo [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/repwn3jm/2/)